# Change --output-directory from latex code in TeXstudio

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, output-directory

I have several folders. Inside each folder there is a `.tex` file. What I want is to generate the pdf in the same folder as the `.tex` file.

I know that I can change this parameter:

[image]

However, it changes the directory for all pdfs.

¿Is there any way to change the output directory from the `.tex` file, I mean from `latex` code? (I am using Windows 11)

Comment: placing th eoutput with the source is the default behaviour, you can probably simply delete `--output-directory`

Comment: Could it be, that you are using a master tex file, where you `\input` the other tex files and only compile the master document? If so, then you only get one pdf in the same directory where the master tex file is located.